# Tizen Studio Native UI app: is there anyway to export to HTML5?

Tags: export, tizen, tizen-native-app

I made an app in Tizen Studio Native UI Builder. I can test it on the built in emulator and it functions. It is NOT ready to upload to the Tizen Store. I do not have a Samsung Z series phone. I want to test it on my Samsung Android phone.

Is there any way to convert and or export directly to HTML5 (web app) that will run on my Android device?

Any other advice?

Under export I have tried Archive File, but it looks to specific to Tizen Studio.

[image: Tizen Export Options]

Comment: Native and HTML5 code bases are fundamentally different (C/C++ vs HTML/JS). There are no tools to convert one to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your application in Z series device using Samsung Remote Test Lab from the following site.

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action?os=103

Check RTL manual from the following link

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlHelpDevice.action